# Get NHibernate QueryOver .SelectList(x) from Function

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to get a list of members from a function that can be passed in to SelectList()?

So instead of doing this

```
var dtos = repository.QueryOver<MicrofilmExportProcessed>()
                    .SelectList(list => list
                        .Select(x => x.Member1).WithAlias(() => dto.Member1)
                        .Select(x => x.Member2).WithAlias(() => dto.Member2)
                        .Select(x => x.Member3).WithAlias(() => dto.Member3))
                    .List<MicrofilmExportProcessed>();
```

Doing something like this:

```
var dtos = repository.QueryOver<MicrofilmExportProcessed>()
                    .SelectList(getMembersFromFunc())
                    .List<MicrofilmExportProcessed>();
```

I tried creating method that returns the same type as the input parameter of the SelectList but it still tells me the input type is invalid. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
Func<QueryOverProjectionBuilder<InvoiceDto>, QueryOverProjectionBuilder<InvoiceDto>> GetList()
{
    InvoiceDto dto = null;
    return list => list.Select(w => w.Client).WithAlias(() => dto.Client);
}
```

and call it like

```
return Session.QueryOver<InvoiceDto>()
    .SelectList(GetList())
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<InvoiceDto>())
    .List<InvoiceDto>();
```